# What are the Differences Between "php artisan dump-autoload" and "composer dump-autoload"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I am pretty new to Laravel 4 and Composer. While I do Laravel 4 tutorials, I couldn't understand the difference between those two commands; `php artisan dump-autoload` and `composer dump-autoload` What's the difference between them?

Comment: just to point out though , `php artisan dump-autoload` is not included in L5

Comment: I got this message after running dump-autoload in console
Class App\Http\Middleware\AdminRedirectIfAuthenticated located in ./app/Http/Middleware/AdminRedirectifAuthenticated.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

`Laravel's` `Autoload` is a bit different:

1. It will in fact use `Composer` for some `stuff`
2. It will call `Composer` with the optimize `flag`
3. It will '`recompile`' loads of files creating the huge `bootstrap/compiled.php`
4. And also will find all of your Workbench packages and `composer dump-autoload` them, one by one.

Comment: But you still need to run composer dump-autoload as well as artisan dump-autoload in order to get all autoloads right. Example: After a migrate:make, you need a composer dump-autoload in order to do a migrate:rollback. artisan dump-autoload does not work here.

Comment: Command "dump-autoload" is not defined. What it means?

Answer (score 100):

`php artisan dump-autoload` was deprecated on Laravel 5, so you need to use `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: This is correct. For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding#running-seeders