# Getting laravel to work with Apache 2

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, routes, apache2

So I am new to Laravel.

I am using mac OS X to develop, so at first I thought it would be a great idea to use Homestead.
But they use nginx, which I barely know when I know a lot about apache2 having sys admin skills.

So tonight, I grabbed my dedicated server (which is much faster to download composer dependencies by the way), and I have this vhost:
paste.debian.net/130339/

ll /var/www/AMI
_> ➜  sites-enabled  ll /var/www/AMI

```
total 100K
drwxrwxrwx 12 root root 4.0K Jun  1 20:16 app
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 2.4K Jun  1 20:16 artisan
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4.0K Nov  5 00:18 bootstrap
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  697 Jun  1 20:16 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  58K Nov  5 00:18 composer.lock
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  146 Jun  1 20:16 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  567 Jun  1 20:16 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4.0K Jun  1 20:16 public
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 2.1K Jun  1 20:16 readme.md
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  519 Jun  1 20:16 server.php
drwxrwxrwx 20 root root 4.0K Nov  5 00:19 vendor
```

When you go http://ami.dubstep.it you see the laravel welcome page.

So after that, I created this route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
        return View::make('hello');
});


Route::get('/about', function()
{
        return View::make('hello');
 });
```

But if you go to the previous url and add /about then you get 404.

Can anyone explain me ?

Error log of apache:
[`Wed Nov 05 00:26:12 2014] [error] [client 23.226.237.192] File does not exist: /var/www/AMI/public/about`

.htaccess in the public folder:
paste.debian.net/130340/

Please help ! (modrewrite is enable)

Answer (score 0):

Have you done

```
composer dump-autoload
```

in the laravel directory?

Just some information on the command:
[What are differences between "php artisan dump-autoload" and "composer dump-autoload"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274082/what-are-differences-between-php-artisan-dump-autoload-and-composer-dump-auto)

Comment: Yes, I have done this.
Same problem.
Also, have you noticed Safari or Google Chrome display http://ami.dubstep.it correctly while chrome shows a black page ?

Comment: Interesting indeed. I just tried to go to '/about' and now you are getting a laravel error and not the 404. Did you change anything since yesterday?