# Laravel - custom classes don't work

Tags: php, laravel, classloader, composer-php

I was reading some tutorials on creating custom classes for Laravel. I followed instructions and did exactly what tutorials say:

1. Created new folder laravel/app/libraries/graphics/
2. Edited laravel/app/start/global.php where I added:

   ```
   app_path().'/libraries/graphics',
   ```
3. Created new file in  laravel/app/libraries/graphics/ named Image.php with this code:

   ```
   <?php  namespace graphics/Image;

   class Image {

       public static function hello() {

       return 'Hello';

       }
   }
   ```
4. Used `composer dump-autload` command
5. `Route::get('/'  , function() { return Graphics\Image::hello(); } );` is returning error:

> Use of undefined constant graphics - assumed 'graphics'

I also added `"app/libraries/graphics/Image.php"`line into composer.json autload section, which should not be neccessary. Why I am getting this error? Every tutorial shows the same procedure for this, but why it doesn't work?

Comment: With namespaces you use a backward slash "\" not "/"

Comment: Then i get error "class graphics\Image doesn't exists"

Comment: Because your namespace, including class is `Graphics\Image\Image`. If you want `Graphics\Image` you need to change your namespace to `Graphics`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your namespace just be `graphics`? The current file creates `graphics\Image\Image`. Try removing `Image` from your namespace.

```
<?php  namespace graphics;

class Image {

    public static function hello() {

    return 'Hello';

    }
}
```

Comment: If I use "namespace graphics\Image;" and then "return graphics\Image\Image::hello();" it works. But if I use "namespace graphics;" and "return graphics\Image::hello();" then it doesn't work returning the same error. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `artisan dump-autoload` instead?

It will clear all of Laravel's compiled code.

See here: [What are differences between "php artisan dump-autoload" and "composer dump-autoload"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274082/what-are-differences-between-php-artisan-dump-autoload-and-composer-dump-auto)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to confusion for yourself. I'm resolve issue into Laravel 5. You don't need to add "app/libraries/graphics/Image.php"line into composer.json autload section because [By default, app directory is namespaced under App and is autoloaded by Composer using the PSR-4 autoloading standard.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/structure#the-app-directory)

```
<?php 
namespace App\libraries\graphics;
class Image {
     public static function hello() {
         return 'Hello';
     }
}
```

and now use your Image Class from your route.

```
Route::get('graphics',function(){
    echo \App\libraries\graphics\Image::hello();
});
```