# How to fix provider in config/app.php Laravel that's starting not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, package

I'm setting up a new private composer package that has a provider called DatapageSDKProvider.

When I put the provider in config/app.php in providers array :
'Datapage\DatapageSDK\Providers\DatapageSDKProvider' 
and try to enter in any url, this throws an exception:

'Datapage\DatapageSDK\Providers\DatapageSDKProvider' Not found

This is the composer.json of my laravel project:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "ms/datapage-sdk-laravel",
                "version": "0.0.3",
                "source": {
                    "url": "url_git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "develop"
                },
                "options": {
                    "ssl": {
                        "verify_peer": "false"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "artesaos/defender": "~0.8.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "5.7.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel-notification-channels/onesignal": "^1.2",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravellegends/pt-br-validator": "^5.1",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "league/fractal": "^0.17.0",
        "ms/datapage-sdk-laravel": "0.0.*",
        "prettus/l5-repository": "2.6.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.5",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

This is my composer.json of the package:

```
{
  "name": "datapage/datapage-sdk-laravel",
  "description": "Datapage SDK",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Márcio Winicius",
      "email": "marciowinicius.mw@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Datapage\\DatapageSDK\\": "src/Application"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "providers": [
        "Datapage\\DatapageSDK\\Providers\\DatapageSDKProvider"
      ],
      "aliases": {
        "DatapageSDK": "Datapage\\DatapageSDK\\Facades\\DatapageSDK",
        "HttpClient": "Datapage\\DatapageSDK\\Facades\\HttpClient",
        "OAuthClient": "Datapage\\DatapageSDK\\Facades\\OAuthClient"
      }
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/"
  }
}
```

This is my package structure where Provider is:

src\Application\Providers

And this is my Provider:

```php
<?php

namespace Datapage\DatapageSDK\Providers;

use Datapage\DatapageSDK\Auth\OAuthClient;
use Datapage\DatapageSDK\DatapageSDKFactory;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DatapageSDKProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../../config.php' => config_path('datapage_sdk.php'),
        ], 'datapage-sdk-config');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('DatapageSDK', function() {
            return new DatapageSDKFactory();
        });

        $this->app->singleton('OAuthClient', function() {
            return new OAuthClient(new Application());
        });

        $this->app->singleton('HttpClient', function() {
            return new Client([
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => \Datapage\DatapageSDK\Facades\OAuthClient::getToken()
                ]
            ]);
        });

        $this->app->bind(DatapageSDKFactory::class, 'DatapageSDK');
        $this->app->bind(OAuthClient::class, 'OAuthClient');
        $this->app->bind(Client::class, 'HttpClient');
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            DatapageSDKFactory::class, 'DatapageSDK',
            OAuthClient::class, 'OAuthClient',
            Client::class, 'HttpClient',
        ];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Just changed the composer.json of my laravel project like this:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "http://git2.datapage.com.br/ms/datapage-sdk-laravel.git"
        }
    ],
```

And in Require put this:

```
"ms/datapage-sdk-laravel": "dev-develop"
```

And then composer update and composer dump-autoload

Comment: Do you need to refresh the the autoloader? `composer dump-autoload`? **FYI:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274082/what-are-the-differences-between-php-artisan-dump-autoload-and-composer-dump

Comment: I tried but not works

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need to require it in either require or require-dev depending on what you're using it for. You might have it listed as something you need but composer doesn't know to install it from that.

Comment: I edited the post with the composer.json of my laravel project.